# How to find Anagrams of a user word in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

How can I create a program that prompts the user for a single word and finds anagrams by taking the user words and searching a dictionary for anagrams of equal length of the word given?
The code to load the file has been provided:

```
def load(file):
    """Open a text file & turn contents into a list of lowercase strings."""
    try:
        with open(file) as in_file:
            loaded_txt = in_file.read().strip().split('\n')
            loaded_txt = [x.lower() for x in loaded_txt]
            return loaded_txt
    except IOError as e:
        print("{}\nError opening {}. Terminating program.".format(e, file),
              file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

This is the function supposed to be used by to serach for anagrams.

```
def find_anagrams(word_for_search, search_list_dictionary):
```

Anyone able to help with this?

Comment: What did you try so far, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: You may define a function which puts the letters in each word in alphabetically sorted order and then use that string as keys for a dictionary containing all words with the same key.

Comment: I do not want you to do my homework. I am new to programming and I am not quite sure where to start with this one. I was thinking that I need to loop trough the dictionary and check each letter to find letters that match but not quite sure how to do that without finding the exact same word the user enters. Am I even remotely close to thinking correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter` data structure for anagrams search:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_anagrams(word_for_search, search_list_dictionary):
    return [x for x in search_list_dictionary if Counter(x.lower()) == Counter(word_for_search.lower())]
```

Comment: No doubt a correct answer. A frendly reminder for OP: [Never use code you don't understand.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Well, what kind of data does `search_list_dictionary` contain, words or more complex data structure?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am very new to programming and the course is progressing very fast so please forgive any stupid questions. I was thinking I needed to loop trough the dictionary and first check the length of the user word, then the each letter to find anagrams. The search_list_dictionary is the dictionary where i am supposed to find the anagrams. So I was thinking: open the txt file containing the dictionary, get the input from the user, check the length and then the letters to find a word with the same length and the same letters. Does that make sense? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, your idea is on the right way. In the future, let's make a difference between dictionary and list. In our case, list is a structure that contains words like this: ['a', 'b', 'c']. Dictionary is a container of pairs <key, value> i.e. {'a': 1, 'b': 2}.

Comment: The dictionary in this case is a txt file with words. So I might have confused myself and you by using the The word "Dictionary" interchangeable. I am supposed to loop trough the txt file with words and find anagrams based on the user input.